# How to change background color to linear gradient with colors entered in the input tags and mixed after clicking GO button?

Tags: javascript

I tried to put linear-gradient after dom, but it didnt help at all :(

https://codepen.io/OlegNazarov77/pen/YRjdJX

```
let firstColor = document.getElementById('colorOne')
let secondColor = document.getElementById('colorTwo')
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',changeColor);

function changeColor(e){
  document.querySelector('body').style.background = linear-gradient(firstColor.value, secondColor.value) ; 

  preventDefault(e);
}
```

Sorry for the poor code, i'm just learning.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It worked for me. Check console for error

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because of:

```
 linear-gradient(firstColor.value, secondColor.value) ;
```

is not put in ' `` ';
Try this:

```
 document.querySelector('body').style.background = `linear-gradient(${firstColor.value}, ${secondColor.value})`;
```

The second thing is if you have propely assigned values in first two lines of code. The values of *firstColor* and *secondColor* are elements not values, either strings that creates color value. You should use something like this:

```
let secondColor = document.getElementById('colorTwo').val;
```

Comment: Yes I have, but there are other errors like *event.preventDefault()* while variable *event* doesn't exist

Comment: Also javascript hasn't `.val` property. It is for jquery that is `.val()`